# iOS 13 suspending background service

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

My application uses remote silent notification to wake up the app and send device location to the server. Prior to iOS 13, it was working perfectly. With iOS 13, my service is suspended when the app is in the background or inactive. I do not want to use the new BackgroundTasks API as the system decides when to execute it. Is there any way to send data to server when a silent notification is received and the app is not active?

Comment: Silent notifications may not be a good thing to use in this case, as they're extremely unreliable. I'd suggest you used the background mode for location updates. Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background

Comment: @pepsy thank you for the guidance. While I do have background modes active, was looking for more frequent updates.